# Result of a float calculation differs in excel and python

Tags: excel, python-2.7

In Excel, I have the following formula in a cell:

```
=-4.607*10^9/U3^3+2.9678*10^6/U3^2+0.09911*10^3/U3+0.244063
```

Where `U3` represents another cell with a variable value. 
Currently the value is: `2938`

In Excel, the calculation returns:

```
0.439958753917082
```

However, in Python 2.7, with `temperature = 2938` the following formula:

```
X = -4.607*10.**9./temperature**3.+2.9678*10.**6./temperature**2.+0.09911*10.**3./temperature+0.244063
```

returns:

```
0.439955286816
```

Why are the results different?

Comment: I get `0.439955286816009` in Excel.  Are you sure all of your values are **exactly** as shown?

Comment: How can I check that? I have simply copied the value that is in the cell with Ctrl+C, then pasted it with Ctrl+V, then "A" to paste value

Comment: Select the cell and then examine the contents of the formula bar.

Comment: @RonRosenfeld This is what I get: =-4,607*10^9/U3^3+2,9678*10^6/U3^2+0,09911*10^3/U3+0,244063

Comment: @RonRosenfeld and this is the content of the cell where I did Ctrl+V then A: 0,439958753917082

Comment: And what do you see in the formula bar for `U3`?

Comment: Thank you! I found it! actually the value for temperature was 2937,9422506179, well hidden in another case